# ProgressBar.Marquee not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls, progress-bar

I'm trying a `ProgressBar` with the `Marquee` style. I set `MarqueeAnimationSpeed` to 0 initially and then I have a button than when pressed it looks for the instances of Sql Server. However, when I click start the progress bar does not show anything. I'm on Windows 7 I don't know if this might be the problem

```
public Form1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();             
}

private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
}

private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;

     SqlDataSourceEnumerator sqlEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
     DataTable dataTable = sqlEnumerator.GetDataSources ();

     this.Close ();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

More than likely your `sqlEnumerator.GetDataSources ();` is blocking the main thread and that's why you're not seeing it animate.  `Thread` that call and you'll see the marquee scrolling as it should.

Comment: I put my blocking call in a thread but the marquee progressbar still didn't work.